# Videojs: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: video, html5-video, video.js

I want to play Dailymotion videos through videojs. I'm using a video js plugin for this https://github.com/benjipott/video.js-dailymotion

And here's my code

```
  <script src="{{asset('../videojs/videojs-dailymotion.js')}}"></script>
  <link href="{{asset('../video-js-4.12.14/video-js.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="{{asset('../video-js-4.12.14/video.js')}}"></script>
  <video id="vid1"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        width="640"
        height="360"
        data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["dailymotion"], "dmControls" : "1", "src": "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xg3b7m_meetbuck_creation" }'>
 </video>
```

But I'm getting this issue

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
at N (video.js:68)
at d.s.play (video.js:68)
at d.t.rb.u (video.js:109)
at HTMLDivElement.e (video.js:14)
at HTMLDivElement.e.ba.e.ba (video.js:7)
```

I have searched and none of the solutions is working.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no expert, but your data-setp src property doesn't point to a video file, can it be your problem?

Comment: @GeorgiosDimitriadis Thanks but I have already tried, but it is not working.